# Date and Time in Annotated TimeLine GWT

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I am plotting a trend chart in GWT. In concrete, AnnotatedTimeLine. My Java code is:

```
Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<AttributeDTO> occAttrs = new   ArrayList<AttributeDTO>();
            for(AttributeDTO attr : attrs){
                if(attr.getName().toLowerCase().contains("temp")){
                    occAttrs.add(attr);
                }
            }
            DataTable data = DataTable.create();
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Temperature");
            data.addRows(occAttrs.size());
            RootPanel.get().add(new Label(occAttrs.toString()));
            DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss aaa");
            for(int i = 0; i < occAttrs.size(); i++){
                data.setValue(i, 0, dtf.parse(occAttrs.get(i).getDate()));
                data.setValue(i, 1, Integer.valueOf(occAttrs.get(i).getValue()));
            }

            AnnotatedTimeLine.Options options = AnnotatedTimeLine.Options.create();
            options.setDisplayAnnotations(true);
            options.setDisplayZoomButtons(true);
            options.setScaleType(AnnotatedTimeLine.ScaleType.ALLFIXED);
            options.setDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss aaa");
            options.setLegendPosition(AnnotatedTimeLine.AnnotatedLegendPosition.SAME_ROW);
            AnnotatedTimeLine atl = new AnnotatedTimeLine(data, options, "600px", "400px");

            vPanel.add(atl);
        }

    };
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE);
```

Well, when I show graph I obtain the following figure:

[image]

In x axis I have date without time. I would like to include time. How could I get it?

Thanks in advance!!

King regard and merry christmas!

Comment: I also tried with ColumnType.DATETIME instead of ColumnType.DATE, but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the format to MMMM dd, yyyy and try or try without setting any format.

Comment: It is not possible. Attribute date in list occAttrs is String type. Then, I define DateTimeFormat to obtain date type

Comment: I think keeping data or datetime should work as long as date object is passed.
As per the doc, http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/index.html, you can directly set the data object

Comment: I pass a Date object but it needs a previous parse because is a String attribute

Comment: @JoseHdez My bad. I overlooked at the method name

Comment: What ar you getting if you dont set options.setDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss aaa") ?

Comment: It seems as per the document, you can use only two formats, viz, Either 'MMMM dd, yyyy' or 'HH:mm MMMM dd, yyyy', depending on the type of the first column (date, or datetime, respectively).

Comment: I tried your advises, but I get the same. The time is only on top of chart (legend) but no in x axis.

Comment: See whether https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1047432 is useful

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly explained in google's api documentation, that it supports only DATE and datetime is not supported.

I'm facing the same requirement to store multiple values into same date. Did you find any other library, which can handle this problem correctly ?